# Can I transform XML to HTML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xslt

I have a query that returns data as XML using the "for XML Clause" and then sends the result as the body of an email like so.

```
Declare @messBody as nvarchar(max)
Set @messBody = (Select * from tablehere where state = 1 for xml Auto)
Begin
  Exec msdb.dbo.ap_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'ProfileNameHere'
      @recipients = 'simon@example.com'
      @body = '@messBody
      @subject = 'SubjectHere'
End
```

It works and I get the email with the info I need but the body of the email is ugly XML. I would like to be able to transform it into pretty HTML.
Can this be done in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to use [the CLR for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mrorke/performing-xslt-transforms-on-xml-data-stored-in-sql-server-2005) to do it by applying an XSLT transform.

Comment: @spinon. Yep. "apply xslt sql server" came up trumps for me :-)

Comment: Yeah sometimes I wonder if people even search for a minute before they post things. So many answers if I don't know off the top of my head I can find in less than a minute of searching on Google.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write a clr proc. Here is an article showing how:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mrorke/performing-xslt-transforms-on-xml-data-stored-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: The link is gone. This might help, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/transform-xml-output-of-sql-query-using-for-xml-auto-statement-to-html-using-xsl/.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Col1 as 'td', '', 
Col2 as 'td', '', 
Col3 as 'td' 
FROM SomeTable FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05404640-6eed-458e-9514-80ff8bd002f8/sending-mail-with-html-format-in-send-mail-task